# Cypress element locator issue when using within()

Tags: javascript, automation, mocha.js, cypress

I'm trying to click on the close button

[image]

This is my strategy:

Can you point out what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to cypress

```
cy.get('.cy-player').within(() => {
        cy.get('img').click() // Only searches inputs within searchBox)
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of the below answers worked:

```
cy.get('.cy-player')
        .shadow()
        .find(`img[class*='Close']`)
        .click()


      cy.get('.cy-player').shadow().within(() => {
        cy.get(`img[class*='Close']`).click() 
      })
```